# Why browser show Session not detail date when check cookie on chrome with session made by rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I am trying understand about how rails doing with session, All I know that rails will save session as cookies (default). I try to set session like below

```
session[:xxxx] = SecureRandom.hex(16)
```

I inspect chrome and check cookies, and see like my image

[image]

I want to know why column `Expires/Max-Age` show `Session`, I thought it need to be detail date. Anyone can explain for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "session" gets used a lot, in different contexts.

1. `session` in rails is (essentially) a hash, where you can store key/value pairs for a particular user. See [Accessing the Session](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session)
2. The word "Session" in your browser dev tools means that the cookie is a "Session cookie", not a "Permanent cookie".

> .. a session cookie .. is deleted when the client shuts down, because it didn't specify an Expires or Max-Age directive.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Session_cookies

See also: [View, Edit, And Delete Cookies With Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies)

Comment: I confuse about client shuts down, that mean we close browser ?. I dont see it is removed when I close my browser, so can you explain meaning of `client shuts down` ? Thank you.